# Can PyPdf2 recognize a wildcard

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, pypdf

I am creating a python script that uses PyPdf2. I am trying to open and append a file using a wild card in the file name. It is taking the * literally in the file name.

Is there a way to declare wildcards with the open and merge functionality in PyPdf2? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) function to find the list of matching files, then append each individually? That is a far cleaner separation of concerns than expecting PyPDF to guess when you mean a literal filename and when you mean a wildcard.

Comment: You might also want to use Path.glob